# Tiles/Notecards - Click on Animation - Shiny R

Tags: r, animation, shiny, shinyanimate

Basically i want to have a grid of tiles on my dashboard that when the user clicks one tiler there is an anmiation where all the other tiles disappear and the one that the user clicked goes towards the center of the page and some text appears. Is this possible in shiny?

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(DT)
library(FinCal)
library(scales)
library(shinythemes)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(rgdal)
library(readxl)
library(TileMaker)
library(dplyr)
library(Rcpp)
library(rlang)
library(purrr)
library(shinyanimate)

Div1 <- div_maker(
  solo_box(txt = "Example", type = "default", div(img(src="Ex.png", height = 300, width = 300))))

ui <- 
  shinyUI(
  fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("cosmo"), withAnim(),
  navbarPage( 
              tabPanel("Dashboard", fluidRow(column(3, finisher(css = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css",
                         file = NULL, textModifier = "h1", actionLink(inputID = "button", label = NULL, Div1))




                         ))))))



#HTML('<div data-iframe-height></div>')



  server <- function(input, output, session) {

}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This can be done using `shinyjs` and `shinyanimate` package.